# Using jq to create .csv file

Tags: json, csv, jq

This topic has been raised before, but the responses don't quite solve my problem which is detailed below.

I have the following JSON file from an API call....

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "meta": {
    "count": 3
  },
  "data": {
    "1030907370": {
      "client_language": "en",
      "last_battle_time": 1548555418,
      "account_id": 1030907370,
      "created_at": 1525288212,
      "updated_at": 1548557165,
      "private": null,
      "global_rating": 3906,
      "clan_id": null,
      "nickname": "Knightly_Gunner",
      "logout_at": 1548557161
    },
    "1020786770": {
      "client_language": "ja",
      "last_battle_time": 1548948444,
      "account_id": 1020786770,
      "created_at": 1465998341,
      "updated_at": 1548948547,
      "private": null,
      "global_rating": 4396,
      "clan_id": null,
      "nickname": "black_black_boss",
      "logout_at": 1548948544
    },
    "1018984431": {
      "client_language": "en",
      "last_battle_time": 1548550089,
      "account_id": 1018984431,
      "created_at": 1456254986,
      "updated_at": 1548550089,
      "private": null,
      "global_rating": 1666,
      "clan_id": null,
      "nickname": "doctordon",
      "logout_at": 1548550016
    }
  }
}
```

Using the following jq query....

> jq '.data | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.client_language,
>   .value.global_rating]'

I get the following output which is exactly the data I need, neatly packaged in arrays....

```
[
  "1030907370",
  "en",
  3906
]
[
  "1020786770",
  "ja",
  4396
]
[
  "1018984431",
  "en",
  1666
]
```

I need to upload this data to an MS Access database so it therefore needs to be converted to a .csv file so my query now looks like this....

> jq '.data | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.client_language,
>   .value.global_rating] | @csv'

and the resulting output is....

```
"\"1030907370\",\"en\",3906"
"\"1020786770\",\"ja\",4396"
"\"1018984431\",\"en\",1666"
```

but this is NOT a true .csv file and doesn't work for MS Access or Excel. What I need is output that looks like this....

```
"1030907370","en",3906
"1020786770","ja",4396
"1018984431","en",1666
```

but this is where my problem lies!. I would appreciate some help in achieving the required output from the jq query.
Tks!

Answer (score 6):

Use raw mode (-r)

```
jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | [.key, .value.client_language, .value.global_rating] | @csv'
```

> --raw-output / -r:
>
> With this option, if the filter’s result is a string then it will be
>   written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a
>   JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk
>   to non-JSON-based systems.

Comment: Wow! - do you know how many hours I've spent trying to solve this one?. Many thanks!

Comment: Many thanks for the answer @Yuri and many thanks for asking the clear question!